# How to add a unqiue index (not in order) for a combo box in VB 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm loading a client list into a combo box and ordering by client name, this means that the ID field is not in order.

I can add the names into the list no problem, but can't set the ID field as an index.
I receive the error "InvalidArgument=Value of '19' is not valid for 'index'."

```
cboClients.Items.Insert(index,"Client Name")
```

I assume index has to run consecutively and can't be set out of order

Is there a way round this. I know it was possible in VB6

```
cboClients.AddItem "Client Name"
cboClients.ItemData(cboClients.NewIndex) = 55
```

On Click of Combo would be

```
value = cboClients.ItemData(cboClients.ListIndex)
```

Value would be 55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a DataTable

```
    Dim tblClients As New DataTable()
    tblClients.Columns.Add("client_id")
    tblClients.Columns.Add("client_name")
    Do Until rstCombos.EOF
        tblClients.Rows.Add(rstCombos.Fields("client_id").Value, rstCombos.Fields("client_name").Value)
        rstCombos.MoveNext()
    Loop
    cboClients.DataSource = tblClients
    cboClients.DisplayMember = "client_name"
    cboClients.ValueMember = "client_id"
```